# Oscillations when solving parabolic heat equation with FTCS

Tags: finite-difference, nonlinear-equations, parabolic-pde

I'm wondering if someone could help me out, or point me in a direction of how I can understand the following oscillations that occur when I solve the Porous Medium Equation $$u_t = u_{xx}^{m+1}$$ using FTCS method. The following plots occur for a the following initial condition
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if}\ |x| \geq 1 \\
1 - e^{-1/(1-|x|^2)} & \text{if}\ |x| < 1
\end{cases}
$$
with Dirichlet boundary conditions as $u(x_0, t)= u(x_M,t) = 1$.

By adjusting the step size for space and time, I end up with the given plots below. The surprising result for me, who just learned about finite difference methods, is that the numerical solution does not converge for values where $$\frac{k\ \text{max}\{u^{m}\}}{h^2} < \frac{1}{2}.$$
How come? It seems to converge for values $< \frac{1}{4}$ instead.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What are the values for $x_0$ and $x_M$? Also, what is $m$?

Comment: @nicoguaro for these plots I believe I used -2.5 to 2.5 with 40 steps, and around 2225 steps in time from 0.0 to 9. m was 1. But I've broken it down to be related to the ratio between k and h, but I can't figure out how to derive this convergence rate.

Comment: So, $u_{xx}^{m+1}$ is the second derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$ to the second power?

Comment: @nicoguaro Correct. We compare it to the Barenblatt analytic solution when changing the initial value and the boundaries to that of the Barenblatt equation. It's basically the Porous Medium Equation.

Comment: In that case, your equation is nonlinear and I doubt that the stability condition is that simple.

Comment: @nicoguaro Yes, so I've heard, and mostly due to these vibrations if I understand a lot of the scientific papers. However, even if all the literature states that it is obvious that these occur, no literature say where they come from. I'm just wondering where I should look for additional information to the nature of this?

Comment: I think that you probably should use an implicit method instead.

Comment: @nicoguaro I have used both, but I want to understand the behavior of the explicit method, and why it wont work.

Comment: For that you don't need a nonlinear equation, drop the nonlinearity. Then make it "explode" for a time step that is too high and compare with the von Neumann analysis for your scheme.